# Kiln mercurial repository using F#

Tags: mercurial, kiln

I have a code on F # in my Desktop and would like to pull it to Kiln mercurial repository on https://www.kilnhg.com/. I do the following.

1) change directory to the path of my code
2) hg clone https://....kilnhg.com/Code/goyal-welch/Group/goyal-welch (repository on Kiln)

What should I do next to push the code on my computer to this Kiln mercurial repository? Any lead way will be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that the question has any F# specifics. I'd suggest to remove 'F#' tag from it

Answer (score 0):

You've probably solved it by now, but here goes:

From the directory:

```
hg add .     // Adds all files in the current directory
hg commit -m "Your comments" // Creates a new changeset
hg push      // Pushes the changeset to the server
```